# jQuery unbind Live/Delegate events with namespace

Tags: jquery, events, delegates, live, unbind

I'm trying to unbind a live event (have tried with .live and with .delegate).

When I want to unbind it I have 3 different options: unbind `"click"`, unbind `"click.namespace1"` or unbind `".namespace1"`. They all do different things: first one unbind all click events (is not what I want), the second one unbind only the events at "click" with the namespace "namespace1" (again, is not what I want). The last one unbind all binded events with the namespace "namespace1", even if they are not "click", this is what I want.

When you use `.unbind(".namespace1")` it works perfectly for binded events with `.bind`. But when you use `.die(".namespace1")` or `.undelegate(".namespace1")` it does not work!!

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/uWxpv/8/

Please if someone know what can I do help me!

Thanks in advance,

Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is:

```
$(document).unbind(".namespace1");
```

Here you can try it: http://jsfiddle.net/mPrsP/